# Reduce capacity of an MS Virtual Hard Disk?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, diskpart

I ran DISKPART on a virtual hard drive to increase the maximum capacity. However, I appear to have made it too large for Virtual PC (win7) to run. I shrank the volume back down, but the maximum available size is still what I set it to. I can't seem to find a way to reduce the capacity of the disk. Running the diskpart SHRINK command just shrank the volume, but not the "physical" space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, what I ended up doing was using the VHD Resizer tool (seen [here](http://www.windowsreference.com/free-utilities/vhd-resizer-resize-microsofts-vhd-hyper-v-files/)), which worked like a charm.